# Laravel 5 to use existing validation to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-service, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

Hi I have a problem in laravel 5 existing validation.

In my controller and request.

```
class PostEmailRequest extends Request{
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|max:255',
    ];
}}
```

It will return the validation of an email as an example. What I want to do with my angularjs is I want to catch validation and fetch it on my front-end form. It will not reload the page. Do you have any idea about this one?

Form from my application will send data through angularjs. $http post url "app/postPage" and if it has an error above my code will $validation->messages() will send to my angularjs.

Comment: what does `catch and fetch` mean? Question is not very clear. Please be more specific what you are exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do following.

- Make a `POST` route for validation lets say myapp.com/validateEmail
- Send the data which you want to validate to this route using [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) request of anuglarJS. Lets say
  `Email`
- Validate the data and return validation object as JSON. You can send JSON response like that. [JSON Responses from docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses)
- Read this `JSON` in scope model in angularjs controller. In the `success()` of following code.

  ```
  $http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
   }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
  ```
- Show appropriate error based on scope in `HTML`.

Comment: that is my problem how will I send the validation data to my angularjs code.